# How do I test my home page route in rails test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I want to test whether

1. My home "/" ends up in right controller and action
2. Whether "/" it returns success

I wrote this in my routes.rb

```
  root :to => "pages#home"
```

and wrote this test in my test/functionals.

```
require 'test_helper'

class PagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_home_page
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

And it returned success. But actually, this test cases tests the actual controller and not the home page root route and its success. How else can I get my required tests? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create routing test in spec/routing/pages_controller_routing_spec. In rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "routing" do

    it "properly generates a root route to display the home page when supplying: '/'" do 
      { get: "/" }.should route_to("pages#home")
    end
  end
end
```